# Need MySQL Workbench for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql-workbench

The latest MySQL Workbench 6.1.7 is still not available for 32-bit(i386) Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I set it up it with current release - 64-bit or a older version of Ubuntu?